# How to set the today's date in datepicker textbox in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have two datepicker textbox From date and To Date... I need default in From date this month start date and To date today's day...

How to set default dates in Angularjs Datepicker textbox..?

Comment: What have you tried? By the way, how's this related to Java and Java-EE, are you using some web MVC framework or plain JSP / Servlets?

Comment: What is a datepicker in this case?

Comment: how can i get the start date and end date of current month ?

Comment: I need  set default dynamically to  change for , "From date" is  Current month starting date and "To Date"  isToday date. in Angular js...
MY code :
   $scope.frmdateOptions = {
      'date': "2013-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
         'year-format': "'yy'",
         'starting-day': 1,
        
       };

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by a datepicker textbox.
Are you using a date input?

```
<input name="dateInput" type="date" ng-model="date"/>
```

If so in the controller you need to set the ng-model variable, in this case, $scope.date to the default date you want to use
e.g. to use today's date

```
var d=new Date();
var year=d.getFullYear();
var month=d.getMonth()+1;
if (month<10){
month="0" + month;
};
var day=d.getDate();
$scope.date=year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

I have set up a plunkr at http://plnkr.co/edit/WJ86aB?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much... Same time another date picker is Current month starting date ....i need. the same as above ....

Answer (score 3):

If so in the controller you need to set the ng-model variable, in this case, $scope.date to the default date you want to use
e.g. to use today's date

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

In your html:

```
<input name="dateInput" type="date" ng-model="date"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString()

<input datepicker data-ng-model="date" type="date" />
```

Comment: How did you know to add 'toLocaleDateString()'?